# Hibernate query to get Total number of entries in a column with a specific value

Tags: sql, hibernate, oracle11g, hql

I am pretty new to hibernate. So this could be a simple question for you all.
I have a Table called BuildHistory. In that i have a column with name Status.
I want to get total count of entries in that table whose status value is SUCCESS.

**UPDATE**

This is my method which i use for getting the count.

```
public Object countStatus(String sql){
    Session session = HibernateServeletContextListner.sessionFactory_Dummy.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(case when bh.status = :"+sql+" then 1 else 0 end) from BuildHistory bh");
        tx.commit();
        //  return query.uniqueResult();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        session.close(); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use conditional aggregation with HQL.  Something like the following should work:

```
select sum(case when bh.status = :success then 1 else 0 end)
from BuildHistory bh
```

You might use the following Java code:

```
String hql = "select sum(case when bh.status = :status then 1 else 0 end) ";
       hql += "from BuildHistory bh";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("status", "success");
int sum = (Integer)query.uniqueResult();
```

One important point here is that we are *binding* the `:status` parameter here dynamically using a prepared statement.  In your original code, you were attempting to concatenate the query together, which is prone to error, and SQL injection.

Comment: so what will it return? A count(Integer) or a list?

Comment: @sreehari This should return a count, which you should safely be able to treat as a Java integer.

Comment: i ran the the query as below.  Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(case when bh.status = :"+sql+" then 1 else 0 end) from BuildHistory  bh"); But i am getting a transaction exception

Comment: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

Comment: This sounds like something not related to your actual question.  What happens if you just run `from BuildHistory`, do you still get that transacation error?  You should maybe update your question with the actual code you are trying.

Comment: I found the problem. At the end , i used return query.uniqueResult() to get the count. When i commented this line, i didnt get an exception. So how can store the total count to a variable using this query or return the total count from this method

Comment: Again, please update by showing your code, I'm not sure I follow.